# What is the best way to limit words in string basing on number of characters

Tags: python

I have a following string:

`This is example of a string which is longer than 30 characters`

Its length is 62 and I want to limit it to 30. So result of simple my_string[:30] would be:

`This is example of a string wh`

and I would like to get:

`This is example of a string`

So I came up with following code:

```py
def func(my_string):
    if len(my_string) > 30:
        result_string = []
        for word in my_string.split(" "):
            if len("".join(title)) + len(word) <= 30:
                result_string.append(word)
            else:
                return result_string
    return my_string
```

My code works, however I keep thinking if there is a better and more clean way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the code:

- The first if statement can be avoided. When you are slicing a string like: `my_string[: index]`, it's not a matter if the index is bigger than the string size.
- Then you just need to check if the character where you cut the string is a space or not. If it's not, you need to find the previous space. You can do it with the `rfind` method (find index from the end).

Here the code:

```
def slice_string(text, size):
    # Subset the 'size' first characters
    output = text[:size]
    if len(text) > size and text[size] != " ":
        # Find previous space index
        index = output.rfind(" ")
        # slice string
        output = output[:index]
    return output

text = "This is example of a string which is longer than 30 characters"

print(slice_string(text, 30))
# This is example of a string
```

In the `if` statement, you can check if the `index` is positive or not (if index < 0 means there is no space in the beginning of the sentence).

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
s = "This is example of a string which is longer than 30 characters "
def func(my_string):
    result = ""
    for item in my_string.split():                 #Iterate each word in sentence
        temp = "{} {}".format(result, item).strip() #Create a temp var
        if len(temp) > 30:                          #Check for length
            return result
        result = temp
    return result

print(func(s))  #This is example of a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a one liner which works in all case if `n>0`:

```
def limit(s,n): return s[:n-1-(s+" ")[n-1::-1].find(" ")]
```

Test:

```
for n in range(1,34): print(n,limit(s,n))

1 T
2 Th
3 Thi
4 This
5 This
6 This
7 This
8 This is
9 This is
10 This is
11 This is
12 This is
13 This is
14 This is
15 This is
16 This is example
17 This is example
18 This is example
19 This is example of
20 This is example of
21 This is example of a
22 This is example of a
23 This is example of a
24 This is example of a
25 This is example of a
26 This is example of a
27 This is example of a
28 This is example of a string
29 This is example of a string
30 This is example of a string
31 This is example of a string
32 This is example of a string
33 This is example of a string
```